# default value in hibernate4

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have Object class which is mapped to a oracle database table.
in this class, one column has a default value in database. I used this:
     @Column(name = "FK_STATUS" ,nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default 1")
the column type in database is Number. but I get "can not insert null in FK_status" error.
please help.

Comment: Do you have any validation annotation over your Java field, such as `@NotNull`?

Comment: No I did not use @notNull or anyother validation annotation

Answer (score 1):

As i didn't see any syntax errors there in your line,Not much aware of H-3 as i'm using H-3.

This could be a fix,Not exactly solution for your problem.

Use a default value to your `variable`.

```
private Integer fkStatus= 1;
```

Comment: this is true but not a default value handled in database. when I change the default value in database, I have to change the source code

Comment: @NGS True , but `@Column(name = "FK_STATUS" ,nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default 1") `  also in source code write ?

Answer (score 0):

The columnDefinition will work

```
columnDefinition = "int default 1" (should be "default 1")
```

but you have to recreate DB tables first. It will set your column to set null values as int 1

Well, you should recreate DB via

**persistence.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

or do it manually

```
update {TABLE} 
set FK_STATUS = 1 
where status is null;

alter table {TABLE} modify (FK_STATUS default 1 NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

@NGS, The constraints such as unique, nullable, default etc.. are the keywords which the JPA/Hibernate will use during the table creation. It doesn't have any significance after table creation.
For E.g., If you create a table first with a column as non-unique, and if you are planning to control the uniqueness of the column by providing annotation, will not work.

All those kind of metadata are provided for the table creation.

Comment: I don't want to change the structure, I have made my table and a field of it has a default value generated by DB. I am going to set value in it using hibernate, but "can not insert null value" error appear.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do small correction in your Hibernate-Mapping Column code , please see below

```
@Column(name = "FK_STATUS" ,nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int(10) default 1")
```

Used this and let me know , If this is not working with your code

Comment: Please provide us your entity class code and the stack trace of your exception , you are getting.